# MS Create GDAP relationship

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create GDAP relationship request using MS Graph endpoint

```
POST /beta/tenantRelationships/delegatedAdminRelationships
```

I am getting an access token from Azure app that has the application permission `DelegatedAdminRelationship.ReadWrite.All` granted to it.

I verified that the request header contains a bearer access token and that the token contains

```
"roles": [DelegatedAdminRelationship.ReadWrite.All]
```

However I am receiving the error: `forbiddenUserDoesNotHaveAccess`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tenantrelationship-post-delegatedadminrelationships?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) the required scope for `DelegatedAdminRelationship.ReadWrite.All` permission is only `delegated`.

`Application` permission type is not supported.

Comment: I changed the permission type to Delegated and am still receiving the same error